# Get transaction after certain (tx, block, time or other) using insight-api Bitcoin CASH

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-cash, blockchain-fork, gettransaction

Now i can get all transactions by address (Bitcoin Cash) using this request to api:

https://test-bch-insight.bitpay.com/api/txs/?address=qptaxxrqcz7qunclcvlcza9an6qlqqhzlya2d4e4fn

But i want to get transactions only after certain moment(tx,block,time..). Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can cheat and use the query for Multiple Addresses, where search is available in a certain range of transactions, specifying the parameters from and to.

https://github.com/bitpay/insight-api#transactions-for-multiple-addresses

https://test-bch-insight.bitpay.com/api/addrs/qptaxxrqcz7qunclcvlcza9an6qlqqhzlya2d4e4fn/txs?from=2

If I want last tx:

https://test-bch-insight.bitpay.com/api/addrs/qptaxxrqcz7qunclcvlcza9an6qlqqhzlya2d4e4fn/txs?to=1